# Typo3: Use the Metadata from Hom Page

Tags: metadata, typo3

I'm using Typo3 and use the fields "metadata" on each page in order to specify the metadata.

I realize this with the following TypoScript code:

```
page.meta.keywords.field = keywords
page.meta.description.field = description
page.meta.robots= index, follow
```

Now I would like on the sides where no metadata is specified using the data from the home page. How can I realize the best?

Comment: Ok fixed! it works with the following ts: page.meta.description = {$meta.description}
page.meta.description.override.field = description
page.meta.keywords = {$meta.keywords}
page.meta.keywords.override.field = keywords
page.meta.robots= index, follow

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of sliding content. This involves a little setup, but will make life alot easier for people maintaining the site.

You will need to add or alter the following line inside typo3conf/localconf.php

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['addRootLineFields'] = ',description,keywords';
```

After that you can change your metadata like this:

```
page.meta.keywords.data = levelfield : -1 , keywords , slide
page.meta.description.data = levelfield : -1 , description , slide
```

Make sure to clear all cache. Then fill in the default values inside of the root-page (most of the times uid=1).

Now you can on any page override this setting, and it is automatically applied to all subpages of that page as well =)